# Exception Handling in /clr MFC Application (compiled with /EHa)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, command-line-interface

We have a large MFC application that is in the process of being updated. It has been modified to add in some .NET components (some of the DLLs now have managed & native classes), the idea is that the old code will be phased out *eventually*.

The app has many DLLs with native C++ classes exported, and used by the application.

On trying to test the app we now find **ANY** exception seems to cause the app to crash, even though these exceptions are in theory being caught in the same function.

example:

```
CString AddressClass::GetPostalAddress()
{
    CString address;
    try {
        address = (LPCSTR)(_bstr_t)m_pCommand->GetParameters()->Item["PostalAddress"]->Value;
    }
    catch ( _com_error& )//exception occurs if postal address is NULL
    {
        address = _T("");
    }
    return address;
}
```

The _com_error is not being caught when compiling with /clr and /EHa (Vs2015 update 3). Without /clr it works fine and has been operational for years. From the documentation I have read my understanding is this should work, but clearly I am mistaken.

The code responsible for generating the error is in comutil.h:

```
inline void CheckError(HRESULT hr)
{
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        _com_issue_error(hr);
    }
}
```

The information from the debugger is:

> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in XXX.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
>
> Additional information: External component has thrown an exception.

Is there anyway to get this working without rewriting huge amounts of code?

Thanks.

Comment: Generally speaking: You should *not* **compile** these with /clr. Separate your old code vs your new CLR-using code, just compile new code with /clr, compile old code/files directly native. You can still link everything together in a clr-enabled DLL.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, and I am sure you are correct. Is this something I should have known about? I have spent a lot of time looking for this *solution*.

Comment: Should have known? I dare say not. It's something that I personally only "got" after several iterations. Personally, I use the /clr stuff only for glue code, but your situation seems slightly more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from short comment, since it seems to have helped:

Generally speaking: You should *not* **compile** these with /clr. Separate your old code vs your new CLR-using code, just compile new code with /clr, compile old code/files directly native. You can still link everything together in a clr-enabled DLL.

What we do is to compile all the native stuff in separate static LIB projects, and then link these into /clr enabled projects - having separate compiler switches for individual source files inside one project is always a tad confusing. But then, it may still be the way to go for you. Depends on the mixture and calling patterns, I guess.

I'll add that I view /clr mostly as a rather powerful glue system, than something you should target for the full app stack.